# The entity type 'UserBase' cannot be mapped to a table because it is derived from 'User'. Only base entity types can be mapped to a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Problem: We have three tables that are inherited as follows

```
public class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

  

    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedByUserId")]
    public User ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
  
}

[Table("User", Schema = "AAA")]
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; }
    }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlock { get; set; }
  
}

[Table("UserBase", Schema = "AAA")]
public class UserBase:User
{

    public string CityName { get; set; }
   
}
```

Add-Migration ef1 
I want to run using .NET Core 3.1. This is the error:

> The entity type 'UserBase' cannot be mapped to a table because it is derived from 'User'. Only base
> entity types can be mapped to a table.

Comment: Do you expect to have two tables with nearly the same columns (i.e., with one of the tables having one more column), or do you expect to have a second table [`UserBase`] that has a `CityName` column and a possible one-to-one relationship with a `User` entity.  Inheritance doesn't really fit well into the definition of the relational world

Comment: Hi,It was just like that. I wanted to know if it was reasonable to use it

Comment: Calling a derived class , somethingBase -> confusing...

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you would have to go to EF Core 5.0 to have this kind of behavior (Table per Type)
[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration)